# Expirable Download Links in PHP

Tags: php

I know there are similar posts about this topic, but I couldn't figure it out. Because I'm new to this area.

1. I have a website host and a download host. I want to upload my **.rar** files to **my download host** and provide a download link for 48 hours access. Like this: (although the file name is **a.rar** for example, the URL is something else)

`www.example.com/sdf3r234/dfsf3434fd368jmnvnbvb34.rar`

My website is ready and this is the last part and the most challenging & important part. I don't know what to read or do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use linux symlinks. Keep your rar files in a separate place, not reachable from the internet. Create a symlink in your document root pointing at the rar file you want, add into a database table with date and time and delete both record and symlink it after 48 hours.

If you don't/can't use a database, include date and time in symlink name and run a script every hour to clean them up, using glob() to retrive symlink list, parse date and time from file name, then decide which are to be deleted.

About `ln` command:

```
ln -s /home/myuser/rarstorage/originalrarfile.rar /var/www/download/201712171536randomcharacters.rar
```

I assume your rar files are stored in `/home/myuser/rarstorage`. This directory is not reachable from any url.

I assume your website is in `/var/www`.

`ln` command creates a symbolic link to your `originalrarfile.rar` inside `/var/www/download`. In my example I included date and time with format yyyymmddhhii into symbolic link name.

Try this manually if you have shell access.

You can achieve same result with [symlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php) PHP command.

To check if a download is expired, use [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function to list all symlinks.
You have an array of files. Parse every name and transform into date and time, compare with current date and time, decide if symlink has to be deleted or not.

You should check every hour for expired files, so you'd better use a cronjob or simulate it in some other way if your hosting doesn't allow cron.

If your provider doesn't allow directories outside document root, just create `rarstorage` directory inside document root and block any access to it with this .htaccess file:

```
deny from all
```

Comment: Last question: And with this process, I can make different symlinks with different user requests. right?

Comment: Yes, you can easily add an unique identifier like a numeric id. Consider this filename: `201712171536-482-xn2nsalsh3hasqw.rar` you have datetime, unique id, random characters.

Comment: Gosh. I'm on a shared hosting and when I run symlink() function it says: symlink() has been disabled for security reasons in .... . Sent a ticket. seems you can't enable functions. I want to prepare it using database.

Comment: This make things more complex to handle. There is another approach based on mod_rewrite but it requires a lot of code and you handling file send in php. Consider upgrading to a better hosting.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the expire date to your URL and check it in PHP - if the date is in the future, serve the file, otherwise fail. Yes, in this simple approach, an attacker could just tamper the data and change the expire date. So, you could add another URL parameter containing a secure hash over the date and a secret only known by you - if the hash is missing or hashing the secret and your expire date does not match the provided hash, the file must not be served.

This is a bit easier than Ghigo's approach as you do not need a database